# Where must I retrieve the application's base Uri / root path?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

If my ASP.NET MVC application is deployed at the url http://www.foobar.com/app, then I want to be able to get this root Url.

I want to therefore do this at some place:

```
var scheme = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme;
var host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
var port = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.IsDefaultPort 
           ? 
           string.Empty : string.Format(":{0}", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port);

var applicationRootUrl = 
          string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", scheme, host, port);
```

**Option A**
If I do it in the `Application_Start` even in `Global.asax`, the `HttpContext.Current.Request` is not available at that time.

**Option B**
I could do it in some event where a user request arrives (`BeginRequest`, I think or something. Don't know its name but can look it up), and check if I already have the base path then I don't reconstruct the path, otherwise I do construct the path of the application.

**Option C**
I could write an HTTP Module or an Action Filter for this.

However, options B and C will compromise performance slightly as they will perform this check with every request, even though they will only construct the Url with the first request.

So, where do I construct the base url of my application?

**PS: I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 and targeting v4.6 of the .NET framework (and hence v4.6 of ASP.NET as well).**

Comment: can  you not just create a static method in a static class and just call that whenever you need it?

Comment: @JamieD77 Exactly. The question is *when* to call it so it doesn't cost a check every time.

Comment: that's hard to say since it's not real clear what you're wanting to do with it.

Comment: I'd just shove it into cache and check if I needed to populate it on each request. Checking for a variable in memory is very quick and, unless you're doing millions of very simple requests with no database access or network access then you're not even going to notice that time. This seems like a case of premature optimization.

Comment: Thanks, @stimms. You're right. It could be no big whoop. I was just wondering what the best of the brains did and if was something better than I could think up. I've finished an app that I am optimizing now. Presently and up until now, I've had this coming from a config file during app start up. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the RootURI once time and store it somewhere (Application variable, Memory Cache, ...) then reuse it later.

For example:

```
public static GetRootUri()
{
  if (Application["RootUri"] == null)
  {
     var rootUri = ConstructRootUriHere();
     Application["RootUri"] = rootUri;
  }

   return Application["RootUri"] as string;
}
```

Anyway I do not think you need to do this as it should not affect performance at all so it is not worth it.